# Istio not serving kubernetes pods static files on Virtual service Jupyter Notebook pod

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to write an Istio virtual service that routes the Jupyter notebook pods to a certain prefix.

Inside my virtual service I have:

```
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-1/ingress-gateway-1
  hosts:
  - my.domain.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /my-custom-prefix/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-jupyter-notbook-service
        port:
          number: 8888
```

When I go to `my.domain.com/my-custom-prefix/lab` - I can see that the page returns a status **200**.

However, the page does not complete loading, as the static file are rewritten to **/**. So inside the network tab I can see that static files at `my.domain.com/static/lab/...` throw a 404 error. However, if I manually go `my.domain.com/my-custom-prefix/static/lab/...` I can see that the file is loaded successfully.

If I remove the rewrite policy then the react files fail to load and other static file are not loaded - how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try change the `prefix` to `/my-custom-prefix` (without the tailing slash).

Answer (score 0):

I want to help you to resolve the issue you are facing.

```
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-1/ingress-gateway-1
  hosts:
  - my.domain.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/my-custom-prefix/"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-jupyter-notbook-service
        port:
          number: 8888
```

As per from the reference [Istio:Virtual Service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService) there were missing the quotation marks.

Let me know if this resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

seems your static file point to `/static/lab/...` instead of `/my-custom-prefix/static/lab/...` in the web page.

if you are using create-react-app

you could set `PUBLIC_URL` when building the react app

```
docker build --build-arg PUBLIC_URL=/my-custom-prefix -t ...
```

in the docker file to build the react image

```
...
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ARG PUBLIC_URL
ENV PUBLIC_URL=${PUBLIC_URL}
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]
RUN npm install --production
...
```

then the static file link in the react web page should start with `/my-custom-prefix/static/...`

hope this resolve your issue.